# Missing(?) Python 2.7 framework on mac

Tags: python

I've installed Python 2.7 (32-bit) version on my mac with an apparently successful installation (according to the installer), but when I try to locate it in System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions the versions only go up to 2.6. From the terminal, however, I get:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86882M, Nov 30 2010, 09:39:13) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5494)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/wxPython-unicode-2.8.12.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/wxPython-unicode-2.8.12.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-mac-unicode', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/wxPython-unicode-2.8.12.0/lib/python2.7']
```

Any explanation as to why this is the case would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Wow, fast response! Using the Python installer from python.org (python.dmkg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see, it's been installed in

```
/Library/Frameworks
```

rather than

```
/System/Library/Frameworks
```

Although I've never given it too much thought, I assume the former is for user-supplied frameworks, and the latter for "official" frameworks supplied by system patches.

Comment: Hmm, but because its from the sys.path doesn't that mean it shoud be in System/Library...? the alternative doesn't seem to exist either.

Comment: Ha! Sorry, I was being an idiot. You're completely right. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone who has done something bad to its /Python.Frameworks/....

Try to install Python again from Python's website, using the installer. https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2713/

Comment: Thank you for this.  I thought I broke something as the frameworks were missing.  `ls -lah /System/Library/Frameworks/ | grep python` & `ls -lah /Library/Frameworks/ | grep python` both returned nothing.  Turns out this is intentional as part of the Xcode updates.  Found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19758680/1896134

Comment: Technical Note TN2328 `Due to both long-term and recent issues, it was decided to remove Python from the SDK.` https://web.archive.org/web/20131215220201/https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2328/_index.html