# Python.framework is missing from OS X 10.9 SDK. Why? Also: Workaround?

Tags: python, xcode, macos, sdk, osx-mavericks

## **System**:

- OS X Mavericks 10.9 13A603
- Xcode Version 5.0.1 (5A2053)

## **Problem:**

**Python.framework** seems to be missing from Xcode's 10.9 SDK.

Python.framework exists in the Xcode 10.8 SDK:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
```

However, it is missing from my Xcode 10.9 SDK here:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/
```

This is odd, because Python.framework is still available to users on 10.9 systems here:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
```

Has Python.framework been intentionally removed from the 10.9 SDK? Is this a not-so-subtle hint from Apple to stop using this framework? Or am I just confused?

## Notes:

This matters because I have a OS X application which links against Python.framework. It seems I cannot build my application with a **Base SDK** build setting of **10.9** since Python.framework is missing, and I must link to it.

I am interested in both explanations for why this framework is missing (or why I'm wrong and it's actually not missing), as well as suggestions for workarounds.

Comment: Since this is a brand-new issue that the Homebrew, MacPorts, etc. communities are just getting to work on, you probably want to search for matching bugs on both of their trackers, as well as look at all of the Related links on the right side here, because the chances that someone will post the answer to your question before all the dozens of others seem pretty slim.

Comment: (By the way, it's not _actually_ brand new, it's just that until recently all discussion of it was on NDA forums… But I personally didn't find an answer for them a few months ago, and put it off until later… and now I guess it's later…)

Comment: can you not just directly link to the /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework?

Comment: @abarnert macports at least should not have this issue as this sort of thing is why it uses its own version of libraries, python etc

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There was an official Apple support page on the subject:

[Changes To Embedding Python Using Xcode 5.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20131215220201/https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2328/_index.html)

Basically, what they say is that the method for integrating with Python with the SDK `Python.framework` is deprecated, and the standard *nix method of using the `python.h` header should be used instead.

That is (the instructions below are a summary - please look into the linked article for more details):

1. Replace `#include <Python/Python.h>` with `#include <Python.h>`;
2. Include the Python header location in the header search path;
3. Remove `Python.framework` from the project build;
4. Add the python `.dylib` file to Xcode;

As for the rationale, they do not detail it, they simply mention that:

> Because Python is a framework, it also resides in the SDK, even though Python (or any scripting language) has difficulties being in two places.  Due to both long-term and recent issues, it was decided to remove Python from the SDK.

Comment: Note that the standard *nix way of doing things is to `-I $(python-config --includes)` and so on… but that's harder to do within Xcode than finding the location yourself and adding it statically…

Answer (score 1):

I ran into (and *solved*) this problem as well:

```
/bin/sh ../libtool --silent --tag=CC  --mode=link gcc  -I../include -I../ -g -O2 -Wall \
    -isysroot <blah>/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk \
    -Wl,-F/System/Library/Frameworks \
    -framework Python \
    -u _PyMac_Error \
    -o libdnet.la -\
     rpath /usr/local/lib *.lo
```

The things that jumped out to me initially were that the gnu libtool I was using had done the `-Wl` flag append on the front of the `-F`. So, I added

```
     -F/System/Library/Frameworks
     -L/System/Library/Frameworks (just to be safe)
```

Then, the other thing that was pretty obvious was that '-framework Python' didn't have the .framework suffix like usual. So, I added that as well

```
      -framework Python.framework
```

I still couldn't get things to work. Then I figured out what it was:

Long story short, and I don't know why it works or why they changed anything, and I'm particularly miffed that the Python.framework isn't in the SDK anymore (Granted, it was always weird linking to it, but it'll take me a while to retrain myself..

***`-framework`*** just needs to be changed to **`-f`**

Bonus round, there's a Python system wide settings object, as well as the 'python-config' CLI program that will need to be fixed so they don't propogate this bad setting any more.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Python.framework has been intentionally removed by Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/APIDiffsMacOSX10_9/index.html

The 10.9 API diff document from Apple shows it has been removed.

Answer (score -1):

The framework will become available if you install the Xcode command line tools:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: Hm, I tried this, but there's still no Python.framework in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks`.